# How to check if subarray (within array) matches a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have some code that tries to detect if a block (on a canvas) is hitting another block by checking that current blocks x coordinates and seeing if it matches any other blocks x coordinates. The problem is, i cant use array.includes() because it will also check all of the y values too. The structure is someting like this:

```
array = [
[x, y],
[x, y],
]
```

etc...

is there any way to only check subarrays of that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `.some` of the subarrays have an item at the 1st index that's the same.

```
const collision = array.some(subarr => subarr[0] === xToCheck);
```